# Will using pthread_create to create a thread without sync cause memory leaking?

Tags: multithreading, posix

If I use pthread_create to start a thread, and in the parent thread I do not call pthread_join to synchronize, it will cause memory leaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `pthread_detach()` it, it will not.

If not, it has to hold some memory (i.e., a leak), as the return result has to be stored somewhere indefinitely, waiting for a possible `pthread_join()`.

Comment: If I didn't do that it will became a zombie or just can't release the memory it occupied?

Comment: By definition, zombie thread is one that is dead and has not been detached or joined. Exactly what resources does a zombie hold is up to the implementation.